# How can I match occurrences of string not in another string using regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match all occurances of "string" in something like the following sequence **except** those inside @@

```
as87dio u8u u7o @string@ ou os8 string os u
```

i.e. the second occurrence should be matched but not the first

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: @Mark Thomas: You must be new here ;)

Comment: @Mark Thomas: its not that basic, especially as at the beginning regex can be fairly hard to grok

Comment: Granted, it's not that basic I guess, but it would be something that is documented. And the OP didn't even attempt it himself. Something that would make it more complicated is if he needed to only capture at word boundaries, e.g. if he wanted to ignore the "string" in "astringent"

Comment: I did attempt it myself using negating class definitions but obviously that didn't work. I didn't know about negative lookahead/lookbehind thanks to the helpful people on this site I now have a solution that works.

Comment: Turns out it can get pretty complicated with edge cases, as I found out when actually thinking through it. Glad you have a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [negative lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!@)string(?!@)
```

EDIT

NOTE: As per Marks comments below, this would not match `@string` or `string@`.

Comment: fails to match `@string` or `string@` (an @ on one side, but not both). whether or not this is desirable, i'm not sure.

Comment: @Mark Yes, but he explicitly states that it should be inside @@.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm saying. `@string` is *not* inside `@@` thus it *should* match.

Comment: thus the correct regex would actually be `(?<!@)string|string(?!@)`, i.e., it *can* have an @ before, or an @ after, as long as it doesn't have both.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
(?:[^@])string(?:[^@])
```

Comment: I believe this fails if there are no characters preceding or following "string"

Comment: Ahh. Good point. I also realized on my commute home that it would not match @string and string@ as mentioned in the accepted solution. Onward towards better skills!

Answer (score 1):

OK,

If you want to NOT match a character you put it in a character class (square brackets) and start it with the ^ character which negates it, for example `[^a]` means any character but a lowercase 'a'.

So if you want NOT at-sign, followed by string, followed by another NOT at-sign, you want

```
[^@]string[^@]
```

Now, the problem is that the character classes will each match a character, so in your example we'd get " string " which includes the leading and trailing whitespace. So, there's another construct that tells you not to match anything, and that is parens with a ?: in the beginning. `(?: )`. So you surround the ends with that.

```
(?:[^@])string(?:[^@])
```

OK, but now it doesn't match at the start of string (which, confusingly, is the `^` character doing double-duty outside a character class) or at the end of string `$`. So we have to use the OR character `|` to say "give me a non-at-sign OR start of string" and at the end "give me an non-at-sign OR end of string" like this:

```
(?:[^@]|^)string(?:[^@]|$)
```

EDIT: The negative backward and forward lookahead is a simpler (and clever) solution, but not available to all regular expression engines.

Now a follow-up question. If you had the word "astringent" would you still want to match the "string" inside? In other words, does "string" have to be a word by itself? (Despite my initial reaction, this can get pretty complicated :) )